# Check if variable number is even or odd in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I need to validate if a provided variable number is even or odd in terraform, but I was unable to find a simple solution for it.

```
variable "my_number" {
  type            = number
  validation {
    condition     = ???
    error_message = "Only even numbers are accepted."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `modulo` operator [1]:

```
variable "my_number" {
  type            = number
  validation {
    condition     = var.my_number % 2 == 0
    error_message = "Only even numbers are accepted."
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/operators#a-b-4